# Which is the most effective way to build dependency tree in C++ while performing REST API calls

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I need to build some kind of dependency tree in C++ while performing REST API calls to internal service.

I've the API service (maintained not by me) that can provide me some data. It provides Users, each User has set of Categories, they can be nested. Each category has Items. Items can't be nested. It looks like usual File System hierarchy:

```
User-1
....Category-1
........Item-1
........Category-2
............Item-2
............Item-3
....Category-3
User-2
....Category-4
........Item-4
....Category-5
........Item-5
........Item-6
```

I've access to only these API methods and can't modify them:

```
std::vector<User> GetUsers();
std::vector<Category> GetCategories(std::string userId, std::string categoryId = ""); // Empty categoryId = root Category. Returns only 1-level child categories.
std::vector<Item> GetItems(std::string categoryId);
```

I should represent all items as nodes using these 3 API calls. There is a struct that represents a Node - User, Category, Item and whatever else. I must use this struct and have no possibility to modify it:

```
enum NodeType
{
    UNDEFINED = -1,

    USER,
    CATEGORY,
    ITEM,

    COUNT
};

struct Node
{
    std::size_t id;
    std::size_t parentId;
    std::string name;
    NodeType type;
};
```

I decided to put all nodes in `std::unordered_multimap<std::size_t, Node>`. Node id is the key and all children of this node are values.

So, what is the most efficient and elegant way of filling in unordered_multimap with created nodes while performing requests to the API service?

I have come up with this:

```
std::unordered_multimap<std::size_t, Node> EnumerateNodes()
{
    size_t nodeId = 0;

    std::unordered_multimap<std::size_t, Node> result;

    Node rootNode = {nodeId + 1, nodeId, "RootNode", NodeType::ROOT};
    result.insert(std::make_pair(nodeId, rootNode));

    auto users = GetUsers();

    for (const auto& user : users)
    {
        // Create node for each user and recursively get his categories and items?
        // How to deal with parent ids while going through all categories?
    }

    return result;
}
```

So, I'm in trouble: how effectively manage parentId and current node id while iterating over API response? How to fetch all categories and items and put them correctly to the multimap?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Categories, they can be nested*: Is an example of this statement that Item-1 and Category-2 belong to the same depth in your example ?

Comment: Yes sir, it's true.